# Gson return null values

Tags: android, gson

I am trying to convert below response using gson library but I am getting null values can someone help me please what did I do wrong? i am using `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'` in my gradle

```
JSON response
----

    {
      "Status": "success",
      "access_token": "512b2dee-fa64-43c5-83c6-f5bb2fe42b7e",
      "refresh_token": "8339069d-0fe7-4d83-9053-584693cf846a",
      "role": "admin",
      "locationName": "Hyderabad",
      "Message": "Successfully login",
      "scope": "read write trust",
      "name": "Test Admin",
      "location": 1,
      "token_type": "bearer",
      "expires_in": "11139"
    }

    my object
    ---

      private String Status;
      private String access_token;
      private String refresh_token;
      private String role;
      private String Message;
      private int location;
      private String locationName;
      private String name;

Gson parsing
---
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
  LoginObject myElement = gson.fromJson(response, LoginObject.class);
   System.out.println("des--->"+myElement.getAccess_token());
```

Comment: Though it should be working, still you can try by adding an annotation with the parsing key like this..
     @SerializedName("Status")
     private String Status;
     @SerializedName("access_token")
     private String access_token;      
     and so on for every key.

Comment: One more suggestion... make gson like this.
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
LoginObject myElement = gson.fromJson(response, LoginObject.class);

Comment: ok let me try your second option

Comment: not working same problem

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

**Instead of this:**

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();



private String Status;
      private String access_token;
      private String refresh_token;
      private String role;
      private String message;
      private int location;
      private String locationName;
      private String name;
```

In your object you are using `String Message` please change `Message` to `message`

Comment: that doesn't matter because his json response has `Message` `"Message": "Successfully login",` not `message`

Comment: can you please try it and please add whole object code

Comment: @MohammedFarhan please try it